# Unable to get response using fetch in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call 3rd party API, to fetch some data. I am getting the response in Postman, but not getting expected response when I execute my code.

I tried in 2 ways. Both ways I am getting "Promise pending".What could be the reason??

//request.js
Method 1

```
export const callSearchGiftsAPI = inputs => dispatch => {
    dispatch(searchGifts());
    let url = new URL(GIFT_SEARCH_API_URL),
        params = {
            apiKey: GIFT_SEARCH_API_KEY,
            query: inputs.item,
            country: 'us',
            itemsPerPage: 3
        };
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                // mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `secret ${SECRET}`
                }
            })
                .then(res => {
                    if (!res.ok) {
                        return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
                    }
                    console.log("hi", res.json());
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then(gifts => dispatch(searchGiftsSuccess(gifts)))
                .catch(err => dispatch(searchGiftsError(err)))), 500)
    });
}
```

Method 2:

```
export const callSearchGiftsAPI = inputs => dispatch => {
        dispatch(searchGifts());
        let url = new URL(GIFT_SEARCH_API_URL),
            params = {
                apiKey: GIFT_SEARCH_API_KEY,
                query: inputs.item,
                country: 'us',
                itemsPerPage: 3
            };
        Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            // mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `secret ${SECRET}`
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
                }
                console.log('result', res.json());
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(gifts => dispatch(searchGiftsSuccess(gifts)))
            .catch(err => dispatch(searchGiftsError(err)));
    };


//form.js

    class Form extend React.Component{
        onSubmit(values) {
            const inputs = Object.assign({}, values);
            return this.props.dispatch(callSearchGiftsAPI(inputs));
        }
    //Remaining code
    }
```

Also please note that I have installed CORS plugin in Chrome, to allow the request.If I disable it and add mode:'no-cors' I am getting as 401 unauthorized.What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: The reason you're getting a pending promise is that you're returning a promise. You need to use then to resolve it.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting a response? Does your `then` clause not being called?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have  already used then Please check above code

Comment: You've used then *inside* the promise. Now you need to add it again *outside*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked.
I was trying to put console.log in the wrong place and hence was not able to see the response properly.

```
export const callSearchGiftsAPI = inputs => dispatch => {
    dispatch(searchGifts());
    let url = new URL(GIFT_SEARCH_API_URL),
        params = {
            apiKey: GIFT_SEARCH_API_KEY,
            query: inputs.item,
            country: 'us',
            itemsPerPage: 3
        };
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));
    console.log(url);

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `secret ${SECRET}`
        }
    })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('result');
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(response => {

            console.log(response); // changed

            dispatch(searchGiftsSuccess(response.items));
        })
        .catch(err => dispatch(searchGiftsError(err)));
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you are creating a new `Promise` and returning it, but you are not waiting for it to resolve. You can either use `then` of the new `async/await syntax` to get the correct result :

```
onSubmit = async values => {
    const inputs = Object.assign({}, values);
    return await this.props.dispatch(callSearchGiftsAPI(inputs));
}
```

The code above will work with your first method.

Since your second method does not return anything, you will never get your result, you need to return your `fetch`'s result and apply the code I gave above :

```
return fetch(url, {
```

Comment: Tried the above code, both ways but still getting Promise <Pending> :(

Comment: Where are you getting it ?

Comment: At the line return res.json()